# String interpolation not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript-generics

Im new to TypeScript, I am trying to study `${}` placeholder and I am running this helloworld.ts

[image]

But my output is a literal translation of the placeholder:

[image]

Comment: code should be added as text not as image.

Comment: Please change your title as well, as it doesn't reflect your question at all.

Comment: for this types of questions Google gives faster results than stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

You must use backquote `.

```js
const message: string = "My text";
console.log(`This will works ${message}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, I was able to figure it out, you need to use backticks instead  of a single quote.

[image]